# Javascript One-page websites | Google, OG & Metadata

Tags: javascript, seo, web-crawler, metadata

We are building a website with the latest one-page recommendations in mind. Last month Google announced their new way of implementing webpages:
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.nl/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

This new way of crawling (actually understanding Javascript rendering) officially deprecates the old "Hashbang" technique (#!): https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more

We've chosen for the following setup:

- The director.js Routing system
- AJAX calls on the routing handle to fetch data from our backend (PHP, Phalcon)
- TweenMax for animation transitions
- ReactJS components for DOM elements

When we fetch the page as Google bot (in webmaster tools), we get a preview where the site looks the same as for an end user. This is good because it proves Google's new guidelines & seems like the way to go.

The problem lies within the Metadata. When we scrape the page, the 'raw' HTML is off course not rendered. Facebook's OG linter can also not process the Javascript, so editing the Metadata from within Javascript seems like a bad option.

Setting the metadata from PHP seems like overhead because it creates a second location where the data lives..

Solutions I've found (like prerender.io) all rely on the old Google way (#!). As you can see we need some input/SEO advice that fits the 'new way' of Google including support for metadata (SEO & OG).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: It's about using the right techniques to build a solid one-page system (where rendering Metadata is indeed 1 of the parts for better SEO). Maybe I don't get the stackoverflow guidelines, but I can only imagine that a lot of people are interested in this topic after the guideline changes from Google. @JohnConde

Comment: For now we will render the MetaData as is on the server. For future projects we are looking at the principle of "Isomorphic JavaScript": http://nerds.airbnb.com/isomorphic-javascript-future-web-apps/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook (Twitter, LinkdedIn, Google+??) bots can't render JavaScript. So you **have** to set your OG tags in raw html code, i.e. on backend.

That is the status quo at present time.

Comment: Thanks for your response! This seems like something we have to deal with, but what about double code? How would you implement this if metadata is the only thing rendered on the server while everything else lives on the client. Double code seems like a bad practice..

Comment: One possible solution is to serve rendered page to Facebook, Twitter, Linked in bots. You can render your pages with prerender or you custom tool.